# Error checking on stdout: is "relying on ferror" an alternative?

Tags: c, stdout, error-checking, ferror

Does `ferror()` aggregate all errors of previous `fputc(stdout)`, `fputs(stdout)`, `putc(stdout)`, `putchar` or `puts` calls?

At least when not using wide strings?.. (Nor `printf()`.)

If it does then may it be an error checking strategy to check for errors only at the end of a series of putc-like calls?
(Otherwise using `ferror()` and the stream's error indicator flag seem to be redundant...)

---

(Edit)

Is this question already answered??..

If so, please help: *yes* or *no* is the answer?

Do I have to check each and every return value of `fputc(stdout)` et al or not? (If I do not want to catch errors early, it is enough to detect errors after a couple of output operations.)

I surely know (knew) that **some** sort of errors cause setting the stream's error flag. The question was that whether **all** errors (any error that causes fputc etc. return negative) sets the stream's error flag.

Comment: What do you mean by "aggregate"? Once a stream enters an error state, it's stuck there.

Comment: If an error occurs writing to standard output, `ferror()` will continue to report that until you clear the error (`clearerr()`) or close the file stream. If that’s "aggregation" then errors are aggregated.

Comment: Just be sure your sequence of writes isn't really huge - nobody wants to wait for a terabyte to be written to a failing stream, even if the failure is correctly reported afterward

Comment: Notice that for example `fwrite`s might be short/partial too...